# split a text file into words based on words and special characters in file

Tags: python, regex

```
import os
import re
import shutil
import tempfile
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO
import sqlite3


### SQL lite




file="H:/query.txt"
file = open(file, 'r')
text = file.read().lower()
file.close()
text = re.split('\W+',text)
print text
```

I am using above script to split a file into a list containing all the words.
But I want special characters ( .,#,_) to be inlcuding in the list.

I mean if the word is p.player I want to make sure the word is split as p.player not as p and player.same for # and _

What changes should i make in this script.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to show some strange / edge cases where string.split() would not work (split on blank spaces)

Comment: example could be bonjour(madame) will be split as single word i guess with split() but with regex we can split in two words.

Comment: you could use ranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re.split('[\x7b-\x7f \x20-\x22 \x24-\x40]',<string_here>)
```

Basically, I took the ranges of everything outside of the upper/lower case character range and also excluded the '#' range. `\x` allows you match a specific ascii/unicode character by using its corresponding hex number

Edit: I just realized that there was more than just a "#" in your included range. You could also go the other way around and use an **excluded range** instead, if you have too many special characters you want to include. It would look something like this:

```
re.split('[^\w,_#]',<string_here>)
```

Which turns out to be a lot cleaner in this case

Comment: @engineer12 it printing lot of blank spaces is there any way to remove them

Answer (score 0):

Just create a regex that matches exactly what you're looking for and use the findall command.

This expression will match all words 1 character or longer that might have a `.`, `#`, or a `_` inside the word.

```
[a-z](?:[a-z.#_]*[a-z])?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Sample Python Script**

```python
import re
regex = ur"[a-z](?:[a-z.#_]*[a-z])?"
line = "word is p.player I want to make sure the word is split as p.player not as p and player."
words = re.findall(regex, line, re.IGNORECASE)
print(words)
```

**Sample Output**

```python
['word', 'is', 'p.player', 'I', 'want', 'to', 'make', 'sure', 'the', 'word', 'is', 'split', 'as', 'p.player', 'not', 'as', 'p', 'and', 'player']
```

**Live Demos**

- Regex: https://regex101.com/r/vO8aE8/1
- Python: https://repl.it/C74X/12